# utilizar numpy en el siguiente codigo

Tags: array, numpy

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = [0]
Y = [0]

for n in range(50000):
    r = random.uniform(0, 100)
    if r < 1.0:
    x = 0
    y = 0.16*Y[n-1]
    elif r < 86.0:
    x = 0.85*X[n-1] + 0.04*Y[n-1]
    y = -0.04*X[n-1] + 0.85*Y[n-1] + 1.6
    elif r < 93.0:
    x = 0.2*X[n-1] - 0.26*Y[n-1]
    y = 0.23*X[n-1] + 0.22*Y[n-1] + 1.6
    else:
    x = -0.1*X[n-1] + 0.28*Y[n-1]
    y = 0.26*X[n-1] + 0.24*Y[n-1] + 0.44
    X.append(x);Y.append(y)



'''Make a plot'''
 figure(figsize = [50,50])
 plt.scatter(X,Y,color = 'g',marker = '.')
 plt.show()
```

> Quiero pasar este codigo usando array de numpy, el mayor problema lo tengo en reemplazar la funcion append(). Creo que lo equivalente seria usar np.stack(), pero no encuentro la forma correcta de hacer esto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NumPy tiene su propio método [`append`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html), no obstante modificar el tamaño de un array NumPy es muy ineficiente ya que no se puede hacer in-place (se crea un nuevo objeto) copiando un bloque de memoria entero cada vez. Se puede hacer uso de `numpy.ndarray.resize()` que hace uso de `realloc` (C), pero nada nos asegura que aún así no sea necesario reasignar y copiar todo el bloque de memoria si no es posible aumentar su tamaño.

Dado que sabes de antemano el tamaño de `X` e `Y` es mucho más simple y eficiente inicializar los arrays con ese tamaño y luego asignar los valores mediante indizado. Puedes hacer esto con `numpy.empty` (no inicializa los items del array), `np.zeros` o `np.ones`:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



x = np.zeros(50000)
y = np.zeros(50000)

for n in range(50000):
    r = random.uniform(0, 100)

    if r < 1.0:
        y[n] = 0.16 * y[n - 1]

    elif r < 86.0:
        x[n] = 0.85 * x[n - 1] + 0.04 * y[n - 1]
        y[n] = -0.04 * x[n - 1] + 0.85 * y[n - 1] + 1.6

    elif r < 93.0:
        x[n] = 0.2 * x[n - 1] - 0.26 * y[n - 1]
        y[n] = 0.23 * x[n - 1] + 0.22 * y[n - 1] + 1.6

    else:
        x[n] = -0.1 * x[n - 1] + 0.28 * y[n - 1]
        y[n] = 0.26 * x[n - 1] + 0.24 * y[n - 1] + 0.44


'''Make a plot'''
plt.figure(figsize=[50, 50])
plt.scatter(x, y, color='g', marker='.')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Tendria alguna ventaja hacer un producto de matrices en cada bloque "elif"?Me refiero a sustituir las ecuaciones de las transformaciones linales por un producto de matrices.